# JavaScript Display JSON from REST API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, api, rest

First off, I want too say that I have never used JavaScript before so this is new to me. I just want to start playing around with calling APIs from the same webserver and output the resulting JSON in perhaps a textbox? 
Even the creation of textbox must be handled by the JavaScript. I am using ASP.NET with GET method for the API call.

Can someone please help me get started with this? I just need a little help to get me started in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: There are tutorials all over the web for this

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a JavaScript library called [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

You can do things like:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    var $textarea = $("<textarea>");

    $textarea.val(data);

   $("body").append($textarea);
});
```